How to get the "growth factor" of a function
Context
In my statistics lab, I encountered a tricky question regarding the hazard function of a product modeled with a normal failure law. Initially, I was tasked with creating a vector representing years to analyze failure probability.
Task and Observations
One part of the question required calculating the hazard function z(t) and plotting it against time. After completing this task, I noticed that the function seemed to resemble an exponential curve, and I observed that it increased over time.
Further Inquiry
Wanting to provide a more thorough analysis, I decided to explore how to mathematically show the increasing nature of the hazard function. While I'm familiar with the approach for exponential functions, I'm unsure if the hazard function derived from the normal failure law follows the same pattern.
Data and Analysis
The data I obtained for the hazard function (z(t)) in R looks like this:
# Hazard function data as an R vector

hazard <- c(7.433600e-07, 7.991898e-06, 6.691723e-05, 4.364429e-04, 2.218920e-03, 
            8.818913e-03, 2.762393e-02, 6.939488e-02, 1.438000e-01, 2.545802e-01, 
            3.989423e-01, 5.705389e-01, 7.625676e-01, 9.693386e-01, 1.186608e+00, 
            1.411372e+00, 1.641549e+00, 1.875696e+00, 2.112804e+00, 2.352160e+00, 
            2.593252e+00)

I'm need some guidance on how to mathematically demonstrate/prove the increasing nature of the hazard function derived from the normal failure law. Is there a coefficient or factor I can calculate to confirm the increasing trend?
Here is the plot for reference:


How is $z(t)$ defined?

Your function looks a lot like the softplus activation function, $\ln(1+e^x)$

$z(t)$ can be approximated as $0.348774 \cdot \ln(1+\exp(0.671063t-6))$
